# ngHide not working as expected within a ngRepeater

Tags: jquery, angularjs, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a page, on which there are 2 date boxes. And below that, I've a ngRepeater which shows items, that in turn has buttons or anchor tags (clickable events). Each repeater row has some 5-6 items. The repeater is within a Table structure (tr ngRepeat).

The requirement is, based on the entered date, the system will compare with current date, and will show/hide a particular item on that row.

If I enter the date first and then populate the ngRepeater,it all works fine, but if I populate the ngRepeater first and then change the date, usually when you change the dates and press TAB on the date controls that element is hidden in the repeater.
If you change the date using datepicker, then you have to click some element on the repeater, to see the change.

I think there might be something going on with digest and DOM manipulation which causes this behaviour.
Is there any way I can fix this issue?

In this simple plunkr edit, it works fine though - [Sample Plnkr Code](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qu3M0wzWIZTaVdGzhQHB?p=preview/)

```
ng-if
```

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Comment: please share some code...

Comment: try using ng-if instead of ng-hide..

Comment: Sorry, restricted code, company policy, can't share, though will try

Comment: @Ved  - tried ng-if, same problem

Comment: Have you tried confirming that your variables are the values you assume them to be in your code?

Comment: @MikeL: yes I did, I think i figured out the problem - I am using datepicker to pick dates but the field is text not html 5 date type (bound to ng-model) and it has some masking functions built into it, so the values are not updated immediately. Yet to find a solution though.

Comment: One possible solution would be to set an independent variable once your datepicker is changed. That way it gets around the date formatting issues. I take it you're using moment as well?

Comment: @MikeL: yes I'm using moment for date manipulation

Comment: Only suggestion, without code, is to use a $watch to see when the data changes, and update a secondary value accordingly. Good luck.

Comment: @MikeL: That's what I did finally - thanks to your suggestion on independent date tracker variable.
I setup a variable - `var dateRange = {dateFrom:'', dateTo:''}`, then used that date on the date picker control in html `<date-picker date='dateRange.dateFrom'` , then setup a `$watch` event on date range and update the actual model value accordingly. Now it works. Thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setup a variable - `var dateRange = {dateFrom:'', dateTo:''}`, then used that date on the date picker control in html `<date-picker date='dateRange.dateFrom'></date-picker>` , then setup a `$watch` event on date range and update the client model value accordingly.